# Proof for an ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, filters

The question is as follows: Let $A,B$ be sets and $f: A \to B$ be a function. Let $U$ be an ultrafilter on the set $A$. Prove that the set ${\{C \subseteq B : f^{-1}C \in U}\}$ is an ultrafilter on $B$. Recall that $f^{-1}C = {\{a \in A : f(a) \in C}\}$. I have proven that the set is a filter but am stuck on proving the "ultra"part.

Comment: What is your precise definition of ultrafilter? This will have some impact on the form your proof should take. Also, please share what you've tried so far -- even just thoughts about how the proof should go would be great!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk my definition is "A filter F on a set x is an ultrafilter if, for every set y ⊆ x, y ∈ F or x \ y ∈ F." So far i have tried proving that the set is a maximal filter and hence it is a ultrafilter but this doesnt work and leads to a  contradiction

Comment: Well, the set is a maximal filter, so trying to prove this should not lead to a contradiction. But to make your life easier, you should try to use your definition of ultrafilter more directly!

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) answering the question above in comments, the appropriate protocol is to **edit your question** to provide the additional information of your definition of "ultrafilter" and your efforts.  We want questions to be self-contained as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y \subseteq B$.  Then consider $f^{-1}(B \setminus Y)$.  We have $a \in f^{-1}(B \setminus Y) \iff f(a) \in B \setminus Y \iff f(a) \notin Y$.  In other words, $f^{-1} (B \setminus Y) = A \setminus f^{-1}(Y)$.

But $U$ is an ultrafilter, so if $f^{-1}(Y) \notin U$, then $A \setminus f^{-1}(Y) = f^{-1}(B \setminus Y) \in U$.  Let $V= \{C \subseteq B \mid f^{-1}(C) \in U \}$.  Then either $Y \in V$ or $B \setminus Y \in V$ so (since you have already proved that $V$ is a filter) we have that $V$ is an ultrafilter.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that the set ${C \subseteq B: f^{-1} C \in U}$ is an ultrafilter on $B$, we need to show that it satisfies the following conditions:

It is a proper filter (nonempty, closed under supersets, closed under finite intersections, and doesn't contain the empty set).
It is maximal (for every subset $D$ of $B$, either $D$ or its complement $B \setminus D$ is in the ultrafilter).
You've already proven that the set is a filter, so let's focus on the second condition. Let $D$ be a subset of $B$. We need to show that either $D$ or $B \setminus D$ is in the set ${C \subseteq B: f^{-1} C \in U}$.

Consider the preimages $f^{-1} D$ and $f^{-1} (B \setminus D)$. We know that $f^{-1} D \cup f^{-1} (B \setminus D) = A$ (because $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a function, so the preimages cover the entire domain) and $f^{-1} D \cap f^{-1} (B \setminus D) = \emptyset$.

Since $U$ is an ultrafilter on $A$, it is a maximal filter, and so either $f^{-1} D \in U$ or $f^{-1} (B \setminus D) \in U$ (but not both). If $f^{-1} D \in U$, then $D \in {C \subseteq B: f^{-1} C \in U}$. If $f^{-1} (B \setminus D) \in U$, then $B \setminus D \in {C \subseteq B: f^{-1} C \in U}$.

Thus, for any subset $D$ of $B$, either $D$ or $B \setminus D$ is in the set ${C \subseteq B: f^{-1} C \in U}$, which makes it a maximal filter (i.e., an ultrafilter) on $B$.